# EJS extract value then compare it to a string that is not undefined

Tags: ejs

Is this possible in EJS?

Extract the value inside the local and do a comparison to that value and not just comparing if it's undefined.

eg.

```
<% if ( <%=person.name %> == 'john'){ %>
     do something here                       
<% } else { %>
     do something here                
<% } %>
```

Comment: what do you mean by extract the value?

Comment: <% if ( person.name == 'john'){ %>
     do something here                       
<% } else { %>
     do something here                
<% } %>

Should work

Comment: @noa-dev, it worked. I was just overthinking about it.